# Why does smartmatch return a different value when I use the range operator on the righthand side instead of an array?

Tags: perl, smartmatch

Why does this smartmatch return false

```
$value = 5;
print "true" if $value ~~ (1..5);
```

while this one returns true?

```
$value = 5;
@match = (1..5);
print "true" if $value ~~ @match;
```

Comment: `perl -we 'print "true" if 5 ~~ (1..5)'`, besides `~~` is deprecated as of 5.18.

Comment: `~~` is experimental and subject to change (or possibly removal) at some point in the future.  It is *not* "deprecated".

Comment: This is why you should always `use warnings 'all';`: your first snippet warns "Use of uninitialized value $. in range (or flip)", which should tip you off that something funky is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the right side of the `~~` operator is evaluated in scalar context, so the expression `1..5` is the [flip-flop operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.18.1/pod/perlop.pod#Range-Operators), becoming true when `$.` is 1 and becoming false after `$.` is 5.  The true or false value of the flip-flop is then used as the RHS of the smart-match (I believe it will be treated as a numeric `1` or a string `""` respectively, but I haven't proven that).

In the second case, `@match` receives the values `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, and `$value ~~ @match` is true if `$value` is any one of those numbers (but not if, for instance, it's 1.5, even though that's in the range 1..5).

If what you really want is a range smartmatch, your best bet is to create a range class that takes lower and upper bounds, and provides a `~~` operator overload that returns whether the LHS falls within the range. Then you could (with the appropriate sugar) write `if $value ~~ Range(1,5)`. In fact, that's pretty much the only recommended way to do much of *anything* with smartmatch. Most of what it does is too magical for practical use.